# How to extract a string till the end of the line with regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have the following string(contains Portuguese characters) in the following structure: contain `Name:` and then some words after.

Example:

```
String myStr1 = "aaad  Name: bla and more blá\n gdgdf ppp";
String myStr2 = "bbbb  Name: Á different blÁblÁ\n hhhh fjjj";
```

I need to extract the string from `'Name:'` till the end of the line.
example:

```
extract(myStr1) = "Name: bla and more blá"
extract(myStr2) = "Name: Á different blÁblÁ"
```

---

Edit after @blue_note answer:

here is what I tried:

```
 public static String extract(String myStr) {
    Pattern p = compile("Name:(?m)^.*$");  
    Matcher m = p.matcher(myStr);

    while (m.find()) {
        String theGroup = m.group(0);
        System.out.format("'%s'\n", theGroup);
        return m.group(0);
    }
    return null;
}
```

did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regex is `"^\\w*\\s*((?m)Name.*$)")`
where

- `?m` enables the multiline mode
- `^, $` denote start of line and end of line respectively
- `.*` means any character, any number of times

And get `group(1)`, not `group(0)` of the matched expression

Answer (score 1):

You could also use substring in this case:

```
String name = myStr1.substring(myStr1.indexOf("Name:"), myStr1.indexOf("\n"));
```

Comment: thanks this works, but I am trying to do this with regex